# Weird text wrapping issue in ie 9 and 10.

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have an interesting issue here.  I have a link that is wrapped inside of a div.

```
<div class="field-content news-panel-title">
    <a href="/news/">Chiquita Fresh North America Recognizes My Company with Chiquita Green Transportation Excellence Award</a>
</div>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
.news-panel-title {
margin-top: 1px;
margin-left: 15px;
width: 500px;
float: left;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

My problem is that on IE 9 and 10, (though funny enough not IE 8) the text will wrap partway through the words.  on IE 8, at least the whole word is wrapping.  I have tried applying display:inline-block, the width, text-overflow, overflow, and white-space directly to the anchor itself with no additional luck. What am I doing wrong here?  And what's with the part-word wrap?  Of course everything is kosher on chrome/firefox.  Doctype html5.

Comment: try adding `word-wrap: normal;` perhaps?  if you set up a quick jsfiddle for this it might help people solve your problem :)

Comment: Not reproducible. The text does not wrap at all (stays on one line), as expected due to `white-space: nowrap`. Please provide a more complete example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this property?

```
-ms-word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the CSS to the following:

```
.news-panel-title {
margin-top: 1px;
margin-left: 15px;
width: 500px;
float: left;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
font-size: 1.2em;
word-break: break-all;
-ms-word-break: break-all;
}
```